# Replace line after string match Python

Tags: python

So i have a file that contains the line  `"log_path=/etc/log/log-XXXXX-YY-ZZ"` and i want to replace the whole line with `"log_path=/etc/log/log-*random-generated*"`

I've tried to use the following code which I found in another topic, but that seems to just overwrite the `log_path` part with `log_path=new` so the end result is `log_path=new=/etc/log/log-XXXX-YY-ZZ`

I've been struggling with this for a while now. Could you help me please.

```
from tempfile import mkstemp
from shutil import move
from os import remove, close

    def replace(file_path, subst):
        #Create temp file
        fh, abs_path = mkstemp()
        with open(abs_path,'w') as new_file:
            with open(file_path) as old_file:
                for line in old_file:
                    new_file.write(line.replace('log_path', subst)) 
        close(fh)
        #Remove original file
        remove(file_path)
        #Move new file
        move(abs_path, file_path)

    replace('/etc/file/here','log_path=new')
```

Comment: Is this some kind of joke? You're passing that `=new` part when calling `replace`, what exactly did you expect?????

Comment: You're replacing 'log_path' with your substring. So naturally, if your substring is 'log_path=new' you end up with 'log_path=new=...". You probably want to be using a regular expression to do your match. Look into re.subn https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: @barakmanos yes I need to replace the whole line with `log_path=new` when `log_path` is matched. I don't want to keep the `/etc/log/log-XXX-YY-ZZ` part. Why should that be a joke? The thing is that I am not going to know the `XXXX-YY-ZZ` part so i can't match on it.

Comment: Well, you say you've "been struggling with this for a while", where exactly is that struggle reflected in your code? You replace `log_path` with `log_path=new`, and then wonder why it "seems to just overwrite the `log_path` part with `log_path=new`". So the question is rather unclear. You may as well just ask how to do what you want to do. No point in all the rest.

Comment: @barakmanos yes I tried using different methods and modifying this one  but this is what gets the closest to what i want to achieve, therefore i decided to post is as an example. Please look at other topics if you aren't going to hlep.

Comment: `new_file.write(line[:len("log_path=/etc/log/log-)")]+YourRandomData+'\n')`. It seems that this is all you need. Of course, you should probably avoid doing it for any line which doesn't start with that prefix.